# AngularJS don’t get JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I want to get data from a JSON file by using `$http.get` with AngularJS.
I use the "new way" to write AngularJS scripts ([link](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)).

<kbd>**[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/hNsojI8SmKtI7CHQ1Fvj?p=preview)**</kbd>

Nothing happens, Firebug tells me nothing.

I think the problem is in my `activate()` function code, I don’t really understood the promises.

```
function activate() {
    return $http.get('test.json').then(function(data) {
        vm.result = data;
        return vm.result;
    });
}
```

Have you an idea about this ?

Comment: Is your web server configured to serve `.json` static files? In IIS this would need to be added to the known mime types section. Check that whatever web server you are using is configured `<mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json"/>`

Comment: I’m not sure of using a web server, I have just a .html page, a .js page and a .json page. I don’t think there is a server in this.

Comment: so you are running out of a local folder using FireFox. I think the `$http` ajax apis under the hood may not work properly in this case since I dought there is ever any `XMLHttpRequest` involved.

Comment: Oh ok, so I have to make some XMLHttpRequest. And did you meant "doubt"?

Comment: Correct in order to use $http you need some kind of web server to serve your files. Excuse my English :)

Comment: was my suggestion able to help you in any ways? Please share your findings

Comment: After encounter others problems, including a CORS issue, I decided to use JAVA Server Page.

Answer (score 2):

You're not able to `return` at that point in your `then` callback. Simply return the `$http` call itself, of which will be a promise, and resolve it. Also, your console **should** be telling you something like `$http is undefined` since you did not inject this service properly. Observe the following...

```
function activate() {
    return $http.get('test.json')
}

[...]

activate().then(function(response) {
    vm.result = response.data;
});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JksZQqjufGQKICNOuDPB?p=preview) - demo

---

Side note - you'll likely want to wrap `activate()` into an reusable service to keep this logic out of our controllers, so we'll instead inject the defined service into `controller` instead of `$http` directly.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VUqwWBls9b6JHQomYjsC?p=preview) - demo with this logic wrapped in a simple service

Comment: `vm.result = response.data;`

Comment: Thanks, for your extra complete response :) But I think $http is not correctly implemented because Firebug tells me "TypeError: href is null" which, I saw, is a Firebug’s bug appearing when $http has an error. But why does it work on the Plunker and not on my computer?

Comment: that is odd. What else is different between your working copy and the plunker example?

Comment: @Carapatte have you made any progress on this? Is my answer able to help you?

Comment: Yes, thank, but I think it doesn’t work because I need some server to run $http (like cleftheris said).

Comment: Well, of corse. You obviously need to run your web site on a web server, how else would you otherwise expect just about anything to work? If that's all that's left for you to figure out, please accept answer if it initially helped your issues

Answer (score 2):

I see a couple of problems.

First, in your plunker code you have:

```
controller.$inject = ["$http"];

function controller() {
```

You are missing the $http parameter in your controller function signature.

```
function controller($http) {
```

Once I fixed that, I found your index.html page was binding to `{{c.value}}`, but your controller never defines a value property.  Maybe this should be `{{c.result}}`?  If I make these changes I get a visible result.

Comment: If you're looking for "why isn't this working?", then this should help you along. If you want more information on how to write code that follows John Papa's community-contributed style guide, then you may want to post on [CodeReview.SE]. There are definitely a few points you've missed in the style guide when writing this code, but I'll assume this was a quick strap together trying to figure out how this all works.

Comment: FWIW, you can use `[CodeReview.SE]` to auto-resolve the link.

Comment: No problem, it also works with other sites as well. `[Programmers.SE]`, etc. :)

Comment: Thank, classic errors :S And good advice :) But, as you can see in my comment of scniro response, there is a problem with $http :/